# Newly saved Backbone model does not appear in collection after fetch

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage

I am using backbone local storage and experiencing some weird behavior.

I have a Model and Collection that is defined, instantiated, and fetched:

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        localStorage: new LocalStore('example-myModels')
        //note: LocalStore = Backbone.LocalStore -> https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage
});

MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model : MyModel,
        localStorage: new LocalStore('example-myModels')
});

var myCollection = new MyCollection();
myCollection.fetch(...);
```

This collection is then displayed as a list to the user.  The user is able to "add" an item to the collection which eventually results in this code:

```
var newModel = new MyModel();
newModel.save(newModelAttributes, {
    success: function(newlySavedModel) {
        myCollection.add(newlySavedModel);
    }
);
```

At this point myCollection has the newly added model and I can see the record successfully created in my localStorage database:

Pre-save LocalStorage:

[image]

Post-save LocalStorage:

[image]

The next step after the user adds the record is to go back to the list, at which point the collection is fetched again:

```
myCollection.fetch();
```

Now myCollection *no longer contains* the new record.  No matter how many times I fetch, the new record will not be retrieved - even though I can see it in my localStorage database.  I have also tried creating a new instance of the Collection and fetching that but it yields the same results.  If I reload the browser, the new record appears as expected.  Anyone have any idea what is going on?  I get the feeling I am missing something fundamental here...

A running example that reproduces the issue is available here:  http://jsbin.com/iyorax/2/edit  (make sure the console is visible and click "Run with JS")

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the new record present if you call `myCollection.fetch({reset: true});`?

Comment: no luck with "reset: true" :(

Comment: Does this happen in Js fiddle? May help replicate and diagnose

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I added a link to jsbin to the question and it does reproduce the issue (at least in Chrome and Firefox).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model and your collection need to share a reference to the same instance of LocalStore, whereas right now you are creating two different objects. To fix this, create the LocalStore object outside of either model or collection, and pass in a reference to it in the constructors of your Model and collection.

Comment: So everything is working now but I'm a bit confused about how LocalStorage works.  Even if I instantiate a *new* collection after saving a model, the new model does not appear in my new Collection (http://jsbin.com/iyorax/11/edit).  It *does* however appear on page reload.  I understand that I would have multiple instances of Backbone.LocalStorage in my Models but my expectation is that they are backed by a common persistent store.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I have an application working with Backbone.localstorage and what works for me is I first add the model to the collection and then I call save to the model. like this.

```
var newModel = new MyModel();
myCollection.add(newModel)
newModel.save();
```

Im not 100% sure, but my reasoning is that, your model is saved, but your collection is not, and perhaps an index is not being updated and at the time that you call fetch you are getting the unupdated collection.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed really promising! Unfortunately, I just tried it and no luck.  The behavior is exactly the same where the Collection contains the correct number of elements after I add() to it but when I refetch I lose the added element.  Something about fetch is not picking up changes made to LocalStorage until the page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of due to which the model is not present in the collection is because of **Duplicated ID's**

I don't see a IdAttribute defined on the model. That could be a problem sometimes.

Comment: Thanks! I added some screenshots of my LocalStorage to the question above.  I can't see anything wrong with the ids but please let me know if anything looks off.